# How to run d3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, firefox, d3.js

I am trying to run a simple example of d3 Javascript. I am following this tutorial for setting up d3:

> https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

This is also a link where I copied and pasted the code from:

> http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

The codes are basically for visualising a Force-Directed Graph. I created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Juno. Inside the Web content, I have created an HTML file and pasted the codes. I also downloaded:

> http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

I normally run the file either with a web browser (Right-click -> Open with -> Web browser) or on the server:(Right-click -> Run -> Run on server - Tomcat 7). Unfortunately, I do not see the graph. I am using Firefox. It seems I have misunderstood something from this tutorial for setting up d3:

> https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki

Could anyone please help me to solve the issue of setting up d3. Is there anything I need to configure that I have missed in order to get it run. Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Those sounds like the usual places. Do you have a code sample of what you've done? Alternatively try to set it up on jsfiddle, so we can all see what you're trying (and hopefully where you're taking a wrong turn).

Comment: I took the codes from this link `http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045` I copied and pasted the codes into an HTML file and stored the JSON file locally. I am using Tomcat 7 to run the codes. Nothing works. I think my problem is the installation and running d3 Javascript

Comment: Try without Eclipse. Just put your files on your server and check if d3 library is accessible.

Comment: I am sorry about this question. How can I put the files on my server? Could you please guide me to do this?

Comment: I have wamp server. There is www directory.  Here I made for ex. dir D3 and saved example.html file and JSON file. It is than accessible using just localhost/example.html from browser. Your json file name should be the same as in example. In this case it is miserables.json (from the code example).

Comment: In this case, do I have to install the wamp server to get this d3 program run?

Comment: See _https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki_. It says: 
_When developing locally, note that your browser may enforce strict permissions for reading files out of the local file system. If you use d3.xhr locally (including d3.json et al.), you must have a local web server. For example, you can run Python's built-in server:_

So, you can use WAMP, or Python's server or some other server if you have access to it. I use wamp. If you have python or Tomcat server you can use them, but you cannot use the example as a plain html page.